# I want to add a new column in every row interval by using C#

Tags: c#, html, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

```
<div class="table-responsive"><table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="table table-condensed table-bordered" id="evaluation_table1">
    <tbody><tr class="table_top">
        <td style="width:70%"><strong>Yarıyıl Aktiviteleri</strong></td>
        <td style="width:15%" align="center"><strong>Sayı</strong></td>
        <td style="width:15%" align="center"><strong>Katkı Payı %</strong>
        </td><td style="width:15%"><strong>LO1 </strong></td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Katılım</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="attendance_no">-</div>
        </td>
        
         <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="attendance_per">-</div>
        </td><td>
            <div class="editinput" id="LO1attend">-</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laboratuvar / Uygulama</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="lab_no">-</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="lab_per">-</div>
        </td>
         <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="LO1lab">-</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>Arazi Çalışması</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="fieldwork_no">-</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="fieldwork_per">-</div>
        </td>
         <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="LO1field">-</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>Küçük Sınav / Stüdyo Kritiği</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="quiz_no">-</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="quiz_per">-</div>
        </td>
     <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="LO1quiz">-</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ödev</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="homework_no">-</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="homework_per">-</div>
        </td>
     <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="LO1homework">-</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sunum / Jüri Önünde Sunum</td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="presentation_no">-</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="presentation_per">-</div>
        </td>
     <td>
            <div class="editinput" id="LO1present">-</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
<br>
```

There is a HTML for a sample syllabus design. I am developing a C# program that design syllabuses. And there is an adding column mechanism for editing. For saving the column's information in the HTML file, I want to add a new `<td>...</td>` in every `<tr>...</tr>` interval by using C#. How can I select the each `<tr>...</tr>` interval in the `<table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="table table-condensed table-bordered" id="evaluation_table1">`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regexp matches. By example:

```
            var html = "you html";
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"<tr.*?</tr>");
            foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(html))
            {
                int i = match.Index;
                html.Insert(i + 4, "<td></td>");
            }
```